# How to embed HTML tags into XML email

Tags: java, html, xml, email

I have an email template that is getting the body of the email from as a `String.` Right now the raw `html` is showing up in the email.

How do I embed an `html` tag in the body of an `XML` email using a `String`?

```
<body>
    &lt;strong style='text-decoration:underline;'&gt;Background Check Expiration Reminder&lt;/strong&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
        ${reminderBody}
    &lt;strong&gt;Note: &lt;/strong&gt;Please contact Procurement for Employee extension
</body>

reminderBody = "&lt;strong&gt;Employees with background checks expiring in 10 Days or less:"&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Employees with background checks expiring in 30 days:"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Xml email", but in general, if you want to integrate HTML in your XML, don't text-escape it. Instead, make sure it's XHTML (which it is in your case) and then declare the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace for use with all your HTML elements. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <h:strong style='text-decoration:underline;'>Background Check Expiration Reminder</h:strong>
        <h:br/><h:br/>
            ${reminderBody}
        <h:strong>Note: </h:strong>Please contact Procurement for Employee extension
    </body>
</root>
```